# Create a new column which is cast to a string in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

What would be the proper way to assign a stringified column to a dataframe, as I would like to keep the original so I don't want to use `.astype({'deliveries': 'str')`. SO far I have:

```
df = ( df.groupby('path')
      .agg(agg_dict)
      .assign(deliveries_str=df['deliveries'].str ??)
)
```

What would be the proper way to do this?

---

I also tried the following but I get an unhashable type error:

```
.assign(deliveries_str=lambda x: x.deliveries.str)
```

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need try change `.str` since it is a function

```
.assign(deliveries_str=lambda x: x.deliveries.astype(str))
```

Adding mask

```
.assign(deliveries_str=lambda x: x['deliveries'].astype(str).mask(x['deliveries'].isnull()))
```

Comment: thanks, and then how do I make sure that `nan` show up as `None` instead of that string?

Comment: thanks, ah that is so complex! I thought doing something like `.fillna(None)` would work but that opened up a whole can of worms...

Comment: could you please explain a bit about how the `.mask(x['deliveries'].isnull()` part works to remove the nan values and set them as NULL?